# Do all 'or' cases need to be checked in a direct proof?

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation, propositional-calculus

There's a problem from Richard Hammack's book of proof, which asks to prove the proposition:

Suppose $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$. If $5 \nmid xy$, then $5 \nmid x$ and $5 \nmid y$

In this case, the intent is to show the use of the contrapositive proof. So a direct proof on $$5\mid x \lor 5\mid y \implies 5 \mid xy$$

The proof is straightforward, and in the book the solution shows that when $5\mid x$ is true, then $5 \mid xy$ is true, and similarly for $5\mid y$.

In this case, the solution doesn't show the case where both $5\mid x$ and $5\mid y$ are true.

In this particular example the proof of the third case is trivial, and so I understand that it can be left out entirely.

However, I am wondering in general, when using direct proof, and when the $P(x,y)$ statement is compound statement made up of two statements conjuncted with an or, *then is it necessary to check all 3 cases?*

In other words, to link it back to the example proof, is it strictly necessary to show that $5\mid x$ **AND** $5\mid y$ to complete the proof? Or is it that since we have shown the T/F and F/T case, the T/T case is also always true?

Comment: or is logical Disjunction. conjunction is an and. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_rules_of_inference

Comment: "Or is it that since we have shown the T/F and F/T case, the T/T case is also always true?" Nitpicking comemnt : when you have checked case $5|x$, this is not T/F: you have not assumed that $5$ does **not** divide $y$. This it is T/F as well as T/T.

Comment: To formulate it generally : You want to show $$A\cap B\implies C$$ Suppose, you have shown $A\implies C$ and $B\implies C$. If we assume $A\cap B$ is true this implies that both $A$ and $B$ are true, so we can conclude that $C$ is true as well. Hence we can conclude $A\cap B\implies C$ without a further proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unpacking the book's reasoning a bit,

> when $5\mid x$ is true, then $5\mid xy$ is true

can be expanded to

> $5\mid x$ implies $5\mid xy$, and since I did not say anything about $5\mid y$ just then, the implication is true when $5\mid y$ is true and it also is true when $5\mid y$ is false.

Or to put it another way, when someone says "suppose $5\mid x$ is true," it is faulty logic to assume that means $5\mid y$ is false. If you don't *prove* that $5\mid y$ is false, or make it an explicit additional assumption, then you can't say anything that depends on $5\mid y$ being false, nor can you say anything that depends on $5\mid y$ being true.

In order to make a proof of the statement "if $5\mid x$ is true then $5\mid xy$ is true," you *must* use reasons that are valid no matter what the truth status of $5\mid y$ is. I guess there are details in the book that you did not include in the question; presumably they obey those requirements.

Comment: Thank you very much for this, I understand what you mean (and @Mauro's comment too). In the book the proof requires no assumption on y while proving the x case, so I see now how the TT case is also covered!

Answer (score 2):

The case $5|x$ and $5|y$ is already covered by the other cases, so it is not necessary to consider it separately. The important thing is to make sure that the cases you consider are exhaustive.

Answer (score 0):

To rephrase @Mauro ALLEGRANZA's comment: What you have proven is NOT the 'T/F' and 'F/T' cases, they are instead the 'T/?' and '?/T' cases, where by '?' I mean you don't know that part's truth value.  Since you are in each case OR-ing 'T' and '?', you always get 'T' regardless of which one '?' is.

Answer (score -1):

Consider it this way: If you have separately proven that $5|x$ is true and $5|y$ is true, you can linguistically say that you have proven that the statements $5|x$ and $5|y$ are both true. This is logically the same as $5|x \wedge 5|y$ being true, so you do NOT need to separately check this, since you have already done so logically. Typically, the "and" statement is not considered a separate case, so a proof by cases comprises only of proving the separate statements.